# Can't connect to server in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp.net-2.0

I am using Sql Server 2005. When the connect to dialog box opens, it asks me for the server name. I entered "localhost", but I am not able to connect to the server. An error message is displayed. How can I connect to server and where can I find the server name?

Comment: Which error message is shown? And when you installed it, did you choose windows authentication? Or, SQL authentication?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to your local machine you can also give . as your hostname. 
What is the error being shown. Are you sure you are logging in with the correct credentials.